# Using p5 library inside react project

Tags: reactjs, web, p5.js

I'm trying to use p5 library with react. everything is working fine except I can not use some of the p5s functions like: keyPressed(), keyReleased(). while functions such as mouseClicked() and mousePressed() work just fine.

```
const setup = (p5, canvasParentRef) => {
        // use parent to render the canvas in this ref
        // (without that p5 will render the canvas outside of your component)
        console.log(props.test)
        const cnv = p5.createCanvas(500, 500).parent(canvasParentRef);
        plr = new Player(p5.width / 2, p5.height / 2);
        food = new Food(p5);

        cnv.mouseClicked((event) => {
            console.log(event);
        })
        cnv.keyReleased((event) => {
            console.log(event);
        });
    };
```

this is what the code looks like. mouseClicked gives no errors while keyReleased and other functions which are related to keyboard input give error saying TypeError: cnv.keyReleased is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like normal p5 instance mode, you define functions. It looks like you're trying to do something like adding an event listener.

https://p5js.org/examples/instance-mode-instantiation.html

Also, a few things are misspelt

```
const setup = (p5, canvasParentRef) => {
        // use parent to render the canvas in this ref
        // (without that p5 will render the canvas outside of your component)
        console.log(props.test)
        const cnv = p5.createCanvas(500, 500).parent(canvasParentRef);
        plr = new Player(p5.width / 2, p5.height / 2);
        food = new Food(p5);

        cnv.mouseIsClicked = (event) => {
            console.log(event);
        }
        cnv.keyReleased = (event) => {
            console.log(event);
        };
    };
```

Comment: changing ```cnv.keyReleased((event) => { console.log(event); });``` with 
```cnv.keyReleased = (event) => { console.log(event);};``` fixed the problem. thanks.